# Find how many SQL Server instances are installed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

On a SQL Server 2012 instance, how can I get the names of SQL Server instances using a SQL query?

I want to show instance names currently installed in SQL Server.

Comment: Do you want to know this for every server you have in your domain? Or just on one server ?

Answer (score 7):

Here are some options using what is already available on a server with Windows Server and SQL Server installed.

You can list Services on a server with a name starting with `SQL Server (...`:

```
sc \\IP_or_Name query | find /I "SQL Server ("
```

`IP_or_Name` is the IP or DNS name of the Windows Server 20xx server.

Or with Powershell:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "SQL Server (*"}
```

---

You can look at the content of the registry key `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL` using Regedit.

You can also use Powershell:

```
Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'
```

Key `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\InstalledInstances` gives a list of name separated by line breaks.

---

Powershell commands can be executed remotely using [Invoke-Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer -ScriptBlock { command } -Credential username
```

---

Using `sqlcmd` you can get a list of the instances which broadcast their names on the network:

```
sqlcmd -L
```

Or with Powershell which has the advantage of showing Version number:

```
[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Open a Remote Desktop session to the server where the SQL instances are installed.
2. Launch 'Start Menu' -> 'Microsoft SQL Server' -> 'SQL Server Installation Center'
3. Select the 'Tools' tab from the left side.
4. Click 'Installed SQL Server Features Discovery Report'